# Find missing @Test annotations

Tags: java, eclipse, testing, junit

Sometimes I stumble across test methods in test classes which are not annotated with @Test by mistake. The methods' names usually begin with the prefix test and their bodies contain assertions.

Is there any way to find such JUnit 4 test cases with missing annotations?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this isn't possible with the normal eclipse search methods. You could write a program yourself that checks these conditions. [This link](http://www.programcreek.com/2011/11/use-jdt-astparser-to-parse-java-file/) can help you with reading the files.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old, but I found it by clicking the first result while googling the same issue.

I solved it using the Search & Replace in Eclipse using a regular expression:

```
[   \r\n]+(?!@test)[    ]*\r\n[     ]*public void test
```

**Explanation:**

`[  \r\n]+` A tab, a white space, or a line break at least once (Otherwise our results will include lines with the annotation)

`(?!@test)` - Does not contain this exist string: `@test`

`[  ]*` - optional whitespace (Already explained)

`\r\n` a line break

`[  ]*` - optional whitespace (Already explained)

`public void test` - match the string